# Как сделать что бы новый список из новых элементов шел по очередности как встречаются новые элементы

Tags: python, синтаксис

Как сделать что бы новый список из новых элементов шел по очередности как встречаются новые элементы

Вот этот код выводит список новых элементов каждый раз по разному.

Вопрос - почему это происходит,ведь скрипт каждый раз заново запускается.
второй вопрос- как это исправить

```
# сравнение списков
lst1 = ['Белое', 'Красное', 'Зеленое', 'Синие']
lst2 = ['желтое' ,'Красное', 'Синие',  'Серое']

difference = list(set(lst2) - set(lst1)) # сравнивает второй список с первым. Записывает новые элементы из второго списка в новый список.
flag = bool(difference)
print(difference)
print(flag)
```

После каждого запуска скрипта
Выводит то Серое , Желтое , то Желтое , Серое

Надо что бы всегда выводился список  в такой очередности как новые элементы стоят в исходном списке

> желтое,серое

Answer (score 3):

Сет не имеет порядка, поэтому результаты отличаются. Делайте так:

```
res = [color for color in lst2 if color not in lst1]
print(res)
```